# Postfix - Before Queque or After?

Tags: email, postfix

I want to relay my e-mails, but I want the Mail-Relay to check the relayed mails for spam. 
I am using Debian 6.0, Postfix 2.7.1 and Amavis.

Headers of the messages look like this at the moment - it looks like amavis is handling the message but does not scan it =(:

> X-spam-status: No, score=0
>   tagged_above=-999 required=6.31
>   tests=[none] autolearn=ham Received:
>   from mx.domain.org
>   ([127.0.0.1]) by localhost
>   (mx.domain.org [127.0.0.1])
>   (amavisd-new, port 10024) with ESMTP
>   id c1bRJ7muUUN0 for
>   ; Mon,  7
>   Mar 2011 17:42:35

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have a virus scanner installed? amavis doesn't do the scanning itself, it needs a scanner to handle it.

Comment: SpamAssasin is installed

Comment: You would not get the 'X-spam-status' in the message if it was not filtered through spamassassin. It appears that the messages are being checked. What is your question?

Comment: JeffG - tests=[none] indicates that Amavisd added those headers per default, but tests=[none] means that spamassassin was NOT scanning the message.

Answer (score 1):

Issue solved. The Debian-Packages were corrupt, bug-report sent.

Comment: so can you post the bug-report link, and what you did to fix the issue?